# What does "No Sweep" Mean in Citibank Context

Tags: ira, etf, dividends, dividend-reinvestment

I am in the process of opening Traditional IRA account with Citibank (currently have checking and saving account at Citibank)

Purpose is to purchase ETF for long-term.

Form has section to determine if Cash Balances (dividends from ETF in my case) go to **Bank Deposit Program** or **No Sweep**.

From what I understand  **No Sweep** is when money is left alone, i.e. not invested back.

**If this is the case why is No Sweep option included and why would anyone select No Sweep.**

When I asked this to about 5 licensed financial representatives and licensed advisers of Citibank, no one had a clear explanation.

Two of them said I am over-thinking such small detail.

Please advise

---

**Trade Settlement/Sweep Option**

```
A. Bank Deposit Program ("BDP"). Cash Balances are swept daily into a 
federally insured savings deposit account(s) which participate in BDP.

<checkbox> Please link my Citibank Banking Card, which will allow me 
electronic access to my CGMI account through Citibank Online. In addition, a 
summary of information will appear on my Citibank statement.

B. No Sweep. Cash balances are not swept into an interest bearing product.

<checkbox> Please link my Citibank Banking Card, which will allow me 
electronic access to my CGMI account through Citibank Online. In addition, a 
summary of information will appear on my Citibank statement.
```

Comment: I wouldn't do business with someone that didn't understand their own product.

Comment: My understanding is that it's not that the money isn't invested back, it's that money waiting to be invested back isn't swept into an interest-bearing account in the interim. Are there not fees associated with their BDP?  I'd imagine there are.

Comment: @HartCO No fees for investing back in BDP. I had asked previously and person said No fees. I shall ask again to see if I get consistent answer.